# Is my tree diseased? Can I cure it?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases

I have a two-year-old apricot tree about six feet tall growing in a salvaged water tank. Many if not most of the leaves have one or more of little "blisters" on their stalks, as shown below (each blister is about a millimeter across).

Is my tree diseased? Can I cure it?

I don't know if it's related, but there are several blobs of clear sticky resin on the main woody stem / branches (some up to the size of a small marble).

[image]

Comment: More pictures please,  this is certainly some sort of scale.  An easy peasy type of sucking insect to control.  More pictures!!

Comment: Photo of  the main trunk please including the sticky blobs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok.  They seem the *extrafloral nectaties* common in many *Prunus*. They just seems larger then normal (but also the petiole seems larger and more red that normal, I think because of late season).

See e.g. http://www.botgard.ucla.edu/html/botanytextbooks/lifeforms/antplants/extrafloralnectaries.html or with "Prunus extrafloral nectaties" in Google Image.